# \includegraphics problem, its print value of width in document

Tags: width

I am trying to insert an image in my document with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodisem]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth-1.0cm]{graphics/1.jpg}

\end{document}
```

And that what I get (image below).

Why Tex print -1.0cm-1.0cm?????

[image]

Comment: I think ```[width=\linewidth-1.0cm]``` is the problem. You can rather try ```[scale= some fractional value ]``` to get the correct size of the image.

Comment: Yes, thats true, but here is an example:
"If thecalcpackage is also loaded the lengths may usecalcsyntax, for instanceto specify a width of 2 cm less than the text width:[width=\textwidth-2cm]."
http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `calc` package,

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodisem]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth-1.0cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

or wrap the `\linewidth-1cm` inside `\dimexpr ... \relax`

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodisem]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1.0cm\relax]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I lost a few hours tryint to solve that! \dimexpr...\relax works great!